# How to get this inequality in Gradient Descent algorithm?

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I'm reading [Robert M. Gower - Convergence Theorems for Gradient Descent](https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/rgower/pdf/M2_statistique_optimisation/grad_conv.pdf)
 about Gradient Descent algorithm. I would like to ask how the author applies inequality **(14)** $$\langle\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x), y-x\rangle \geq \frac{1}{L}\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|$$ to get $$-2 \frac{1}{L}\left\langle x^{t}-x^{*}, \nabla f\left(x^{t}\right)\right\rangle+\frac{1}{L^{2}}\left\|\nabla f\left(x^{t}\right)\right\|_{2}^{2} \le -\frac{1}{L^{2}}\left\|\nabla f\left(x^{t}\right)\right\|_{2}^{2}$$

I don't follow how to get rid of $\nabla f(x^\star)$. Thank you so much for your help!

> [image]
>   Here $$x^{*}=\arg \min _{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x)$$
>   [image]

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking too simple but the gradient vanishes at $x^*$ so $$ \langle x^t - x^* , \nabla f(x^t) \rangle =  \langle x^t - x^*, \nabla f(x^t) - \nabla f(x^*) \rangle $$ to which we can apply (14) and get that $$ - 2/L \langle x^t - x^* , \nabla f(x^t)- \nabla f(x^*) \rangle \leq -2/L^2 \lVert \nabla f(x^t) - \nabla f(x^*) \rVert$$ Again the gradient at $x^*$ vanishes and we can insert the inequality into the proof

Comment: Thank you @Michael! Could you please convert your comment to an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist of all I suspect there's a typo in (14), as I find a very similar lemma [on page 15 (PDF page 17) of this](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf) stating the norm on the RHS should be squared. 
$$
\langle y - x, \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \geq \frac{1}{L} \lVert \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \rVert_2^2
$$

Now: If $x^*$ is to be a stationary point of the gradient method in the context defined above then the gradient must vanish at that point, $\nabla f(x^*) = \mathbf{0}$. This means that the innerproduct
$$ \langle x^t - x^*, \nabla f(x^t) \rangle = \langle x^t - x^*, \nabla f(x^t) - \nabla f(x^*) \rangle. $$
Using (14) on this innerproduct yields the inequality
$$ \langle x^t - x^*, \nabla f(x^t) - \nabla f(x^*) \rangle \geq \frac{1}{L} \lVert \nabla f(x^t) - \nabla f(x^*) \rVert_2^2. $$
By multiplying both sides with $\frac{-2}{L}$ (and flipping the inequality) and inserting for $\nabla f(x^*) = \mathbf{0}$ we arrive at the inequality
$$
-\frac{2}{L} \langle x^t - x^*, \nabla f(x^*) \rangle \leq -\frac{2}{L^2} \lVert \nabla f(x^t) \rVert_2^2 $$
which means that
$$
\lVert x^t - x^* \rVert_2^2 - \frac{2}{L} \langle x^t - x^*, \nabla f(x^*) \rangle + \frac{1}{L^2} \lVert \nabla f(x^t) \rVert_2^2 
\leq  \lVert x^t - x^* \rVert_2^2 - \frac{2}{L^2} \lVert \nabla f(x^t) \rVert^2_2 + \frac{1}{L^2} \lVert \nabla f(x^t) \rVert_2^2 \leq \lVert x^t - x^* \rVert_2^2 + \frac{1}{L^2} \lVert \nabla f(x^t) \rVert_2^2
$$
If there isn't a typo in the original (14) you end up with
$$ - \frac{2}{L^2} \lVert \nabla f(x^t) \rVert + \frac{1}{L^2} \lVert \nabla f(x^t) \rVert_2^2 \leq \frac{1}{L^2} \lVert \nabla f(x^t) \rVert_2^2$$
which means the proof still holds but I strongly suspect that there is a typo.